# Fix Header Row of ASP.NET GridView

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css, web

Before getting in details, I would like to mention I've tried various solutions from stackoverflow and net too. But, none suitable in my scenario. So, I provided detailed information.

In an ASP.NET 2.0 Web Application, a gridview controls is used and columns of that gridview are generated at runtime with respect to user's settings.
So, in Default.aspx the gridview definition is as below:

```
<div id="DivListB" runat="server" onscroll="SaveScrollValue(); SetListFloatingHeader()" visible="True">
<asp:GridView ID="ObjList" runat="server" OnLoad="ReloadGrid" CssClass="ObjList" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowDataBound="ObjList_RowDataBound" AutoGenerateSelectButton="false" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ObjList_SelectedIndexChanged" OnRowCreated="ObjList_RowCreated">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="&nbsp" ItemStyle-Width="46px" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
            <HeaderTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox AutoPostBack="true" ID="chkAll" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="HeaderChk_Changed" /> 
            </HeaderTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox AutoPostBack="true" ID="chkRow" runat="server" Checked='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Selection")%>' OnCheckedChanged="ChkRow_OnCheckChange" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

The gridview columns are added at runtime and below method creates the columns depending upon user settings from web.config:

```
private void CreateDefaultGridView(Hashtable htPartSchema)
    {
        string sTempHeader, sTempAlignment, sTempWidth, sTempVisible;
        try
        {
            //get partlist settings section from web.config
            NameValueCollection plConfigKeys = (NameValueCollection)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("CONFIG_SETTINGS/PL_SETTINGS");
            //cond: check partlist config keys exist
            if (plConfigKeys != null && plConfigKeys.Count > 0)
            {
                //loop: every key present in configruation
                foreach (string key in plConfigKeys)
                {
                    //cond: config key is present in part schema
                    if (htPartSchema.ContainsKey(key.ToUpper()) == true)
                    {
                        //create new databound column                        
                        BoundField gridCol = new BoundField();
                        //assign datafield to bind with data table column
                        gridCol.DataField = key;
                        //get value from config key                
                        string sKeyValue = plConfigKeys[key].ToString();                         
                        try
                        {
                            string[] sTempArray = sKeyValue.Split(new string[] { "|" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                            sTempHeader = sTempArray[0];
                            sTempAlignment = sTempArray[1];
                            sTempWidth = sTempArray[2];
                            sTempVisible = sTempArray[3];
                            PLDefaultColumnHeaderAlignments.Add(sTempHeader, sTempAlignment);
                            PLDefaultColumHeaderWidths.Add(sTempHeader, sTempWidth);
                        }
                        catch
                        {
                            sTempHeader = string.Empty;
                            sTempAlignment = string.Empty;
                            sTempWidth = string.Empty;
                            sTempVisible = "false";
                        }
                        if (sTempVisible.ToLower().Equals("true"))
                        {
                            //assign display header text
                            gridCol.HeaderText = sTempHeader;
                            //add the column in the gridview
                            ObjList.Columns.Add(gridCol);

                            //cond: to check the specified alignment
                            if (sTempAlignment.ToUpper() == "L")
                            {
                                gridCol.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;
                                gridCol.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Left;        
                            }
                            else if (sTempAlignment.ToUpper() == "R")
                            {
                                gridCol.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                                gridCol.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
                            }
                            else if (sTempAlignment.ToUpper() == "C")
                            {
                                gridCol.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                                gridCol.HeaderStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
                            }
                            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(sTempWidth) == false)
                            {
                                gridCol.ControlStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(int.Parse(sTempWidth));
                                gridCol.HeaderStyle.Width = int.Parse(sTempWidth);

                                gridCol.HeaderStyle.Wrap = false;
                                gridCol.ItemStyle.Wrap = false;
                                gridCol.ItemStyle.Width = Unit.Pixel(int.Parse(sTempWidth));

                                //set column width
                                double dTempColWidth = 120;  //default value
                                double.TryParse(sTempWidth, out dTempColWidth);
                                //change width of grid view according to column sizes
                                ObjList.Width = new Unit((ObjList.Width.Value + dTempColWidth), UnitType.Pixel);                                   
                            }
                        }
                        gridCol.ItemStyle.Wrap = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

And when rows are bounded with GridView few events and css are also applied at runtime in DataRowBound Event of GridView as mentioned below:

```
protected void ObjList_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            int iDataRowsCounter = 0;
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {
                //get datatable from 
                DataTable dtList = (DataTable)Session["ListTable" + ViewState["ViewerId"]];

                //get position of the respective row
                string strPostion = dtList.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex]["Position"].ToString();
                string strLinkNum = dtList.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex]["LinkNumber"].ToString();
                //get row check box
                CheckBox cbRow = ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkRow"));
                string pnum = dtList.Rows[e.Row.RowIndex]["PartNumber"].ToString();
                if (a_PartNumber != null && pnum == a_PartNumber)
                {
                    HighlightPic.Value = HighlightPic.Value + "||" + e.Row.RowIndex.ToString();
                    e.Row.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor, "#3D98FF");
                    e.Row.Style.Add(HtmlTextWriterStyle.Color, "#FFFFFF");
                }
                //mouse hover effects on gridview (CSS)
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover", "this.className='ObjListHighlight'");
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "this.className='ObjListNormal'");
                //keep position of the row in case needed in javascript
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("RowPosition", strPostion);
                //on row checkbox check change of a single row
                cbRow.Attributes.Add("onclick", "OnRowCheckChange(this, 'ObjList')");
                //on full row click highlight picture 
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("onclick", "HighlightPicture('" + strPostion + "'," + e.Row.RowIndex + ", false)");
                //on row double click 
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("ondblclick", "OnRowDblClick(" + e.Row.RowIndex + ",'ObjList')");                              
            }
            else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Header)
            {
                //find header checkbox control
                CheckBox cbHeader = ((CheckBox)e.Row.FindControl("chkAll"));
                e.Row.Attributes.Add("class", "item_HeaderRow");
                e.Row.Cells[0].Attributes.Add("class", "item_HeaderCell");
                //add header change event on checkbox click
                cbHeader.Attributes.Add("onclick", "OnHeaderCheckChange(this,'ObjList')");                    
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Its presentation is something like below:
[image]
Respective css is as below:

```
    .ObjList
{
    height: auto;    
}
.ObjListHighlight
{
    background-color: #CAE4FF;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.ObjListNormal
{
    background-color: White;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.ObjList tr.row
{
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #1B3A7A;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
}

.ObjList tr.row:hover
{
    background-color: #CAE4FF;
}

.ObjList tr.row_selected
{
    cursor: default;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    background-color: #3D98FF;
}
```

What I wanted to do is to fix the header row of that gridview. Solution can be in javascript or jQuery. Suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

ASPX page:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="gridviewScroll.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            gridviewScroll();
        });

        function gridviewScroll() {
            gridView1 = $('#gridtest').gridviewScroll({
                width: 600,
                height: 300,
                railcolor: "#F0F0F0",
                barcolor: "#CDCDCD",
                barhovercolor: "#606060",
                bgcolor: "#F0F0F0",
                freezesize: 1,
                arrowsize: 30,                
                headerrowcount: 1,
                railsize: 16,
                barsize: 8
            });
        }
    </script>
    <div style="width: 100%; height: 400px; overflow: scroll">
            <asp:GridView ID="gridtest" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="UserID" HeaderText="ID" SortExpression="UserID" ReadOnly="true" />
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
        </div>
```

CS page:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        gridtest.DataSource = getUserDetails();
        gridtest.DataBind();
    }
    public class details
    {
        public int UserID { get; set; }
        public string FirstName {get;set;}
    }
    public List<details> getUserDetails()
    {
        List<details> gt = new List<details>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 40; i++)
        {
            details objDetails = new details();
            objDetails.UserID = i;
            objDetails.FirstName = "test" + i;
            gt.Add(objDetails);
        }
        return gt;
    }
```

For reference use this : http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/

Comment: I've used the basic gridview example from http://gridviewscroll.aspcity.idv.tw/Demo.aspx.I set the size of width and height according the calaculation of container div of GridView. It works fine. But, when I resize the the scrolls are hideen. Why is that so ?

Comment: How display div tag when you set hidden? or I am not understand what you saying about?

Comment: No, its not hidden. Actually, Gridview is contained in a div. In my case, I've remove the overflow property of container div because now gridview shows its own scrolls as displayed in demo. But, we have to mention the width and height of gridview in gridviewScroll() function.

Comment: have you set "headerrowcount: 1,"? and i remove div tag in my code so its working properly.

Comment: Yeah, same settings as yours. But, I cann't remove the div tag as it is main container of gridview. What else I can try ?

Comment: I set this in my code. You wan't this type of div. <div style="width: 100%; height: auto; overflow: hidden"></div> if yes then its working.

Comment: Well, that behavior is only produed in IE. And my target browser is also IE. So, what I can do to fix it ?

Comment: I checked in IE 7,8,9,10 its working. No issue produced in my side.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. Its something with my application. Thanks for such a great help.

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet would be to create two GridViews. One purely for the header. Second, for the body wrapped in a scrollable div just below the first one. Position the second gridview with a negative top margin to hide its header. This way you will use the header of the first girdview and scroll the second one.

Alternatively, you can use a plugin like this one: http://www.fixedheadertable.com

This plugin also uses the same logic as I described above.